# Changing behaviour of the *scratch* buffer in Aquamacs

Tags: emacs, scratch

In Emacs, the *scratch* buffer is sort of special. It is intended to contain stuff that **you don't want to save**. In Aquamacs, it is treated as a normal buffer, so that if I close it, Aquamacs will ask me if I want to discard my changes and so forth.

How can I set the *scratch* buffer to behave like in the traditional emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled via Customisation

Choose Aquamacs->Preferences

Then in Aquamacs choose the Aquamacs group and then look at Aquamacs Scratch File. The value is

> File name to save the scratch file. Set to nil to not save it.